# How to encrypt plain-text message using Diffie-Hellman algorithm

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

Let's say bob says `Hi` and Alice says `Hello`, With the knowledge of `n` and `g`, how can we encrypt those message using Diffie-hellman or any ECDH

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Wikipedia page of [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) you will see that, the algorithm is actually a key exchange protocol.

That is; two parties agree on a new key such that any of the two parties doesn't know before the protocol.

We use this protocol to generate a new key, and transfer the messages by using a symmetric encryption algorithm like AES with the generated key.

If you are looking for an encryption based on the Diffie-Hellman assumption you should check [ElGamal Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption)